# Maui ioS Overriding SendEvent and how do I access the registered services - Cannot inject either

Tags: maui

I need to implement the SendEvent in maui ios and I have something like below
however how do access the services that got registered earlier on in the maui program?
Is there another way of doing it?

```
public class Program
    {
        // This is the main entry point of the application.
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UIApplication.Main(args, typeof(Sample), typeof(AppDelegate));
        }
    }

public class Sample : UIApplication
{
        public Sample() : base()
        {
            
        }

        public Sample(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        public Sample(Foundation.NSObjectFlag t) : base(t)
        {
        }
        public override void SendEvent(UIEvent uievent)
        {
           
            if (uievent.Type == UIEventType.Touches)
            {
                if (uievent.AllTouches.Cast<UITouch>().Any(t => t.Phase == UITouchPhase.Began))
                {
                   //dosomething here - we need to use a service that was registered earlier on
                }
            }

            base.SendEvent(uievent);
        }        
    }
```

Comment: You can be resolved or injected as a dependency. like this `var settingsService = this.Handler.MauiContext.Services.GetServices<ISettingsService>();`.You can check the documentation for more: [Dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/dependency-injection)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but does not seem to work! I get a red underline when I do anywhere in the class MauiContext.Services...   "Services is not null object reference is required for the non static field . I even did something like public static MauiContext? MyMauiContext { get; set; }and then MyMauiContext?.Services... but nothing - not sure how its supposed to work.

Comment: I don't know how you register the service in Maui, but I think the [Invoke platform code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code?view=net-maui-7.0) in Maui can help you. You can refer to this document to realize cross-platform code calling platform code.